# Fastest way to query data by a specific date and data by next older date from oracle table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, linq

I am developing a web-application using c# and MVC in .net environment. The Database is Oracle and connected via the DevArt Connector to the Entity Framework from which I created my entities Database first. 
The Table that gets queried has some Data columns and a Date Column.

The specific problem is: The User will enter a specific date for the query and I will get a List of Elements (~10k) that contain this specific date and get their belonging data. Additionally I need the data from EVERY ELEMENT IN THE LIST for THE NEXT OLDER DATE.

Note: There will be Datasets with Dates for these elements that are younger or older than the date the user enters and sometimes there is no younger date, so max() or Top2 won't work just so easily.

This is what I came up with:

```
var query = context.BsgApo
                    .Where(
                        a => ListOfPznsToDate.Contains(a.Pzns)
                            && a.Date <= UserDate
                                && context.BsgApo.Any(
                            sub =>
                                sub.Pzns == a.Pzns &&
                                sub.Date < a.Date)
                                    &&
                                context.BsgApo.Any(
                                    negSub => negSub.Pzns == a.Pzns &&
                                        negSub.Date > a.Date &&
                                        negSub.Date < UserDate
                                        ) == false
                                )
                    .OrderBy(eL => eL.Pzns).ThenBy(eL => eL.Date)
                    .Select(MapBsgApoToPreisaenderungsErgebnisListe)
                    .ToList();
```

First, I query the table by a list of elements where each element has a unique identifier (pzn) so I will get just the elements I am interested in AND that have a date that is equal or younger than the one the user entered.
Then I do a sub-query because I want the dataset of the (maybe existent) smaller date. If there is one, then I check if there is none between the smaller one and the date the user entered.

This actually works just halfway, I miss some data and the query takes some seconds.

So how can I add the data from the next older date to my list of elements in a correct and fast way?

Comment: Note that `DATE` is a reserved word in Oracle; you will be in a lot of pain if you use it as a column name. Better change it to `DT` or something like that as soon as possible. Then: if `"DATE"` is of datetime data type (or a timestamp), and if it has a time component rather than just a date, please note that something like `"DATE" <= date_entered_by_user` will not work as you may expect it. If the user only enters a date and not also a time, the time component will be 00:00:00, midnight at the beginning of the day, by default, while `"DATE"` may be the same date but with time > 00:00:00.

Comment: are you able to use lag lead in a query somewhere so you could just get your data as a query? or is it difficult to do that sort of thing with code first Entity framework?

Comment: @user2744722 sadly EF doesnt allow lead or lag. I wrote that in a SQL Statement before just to see there is no counterpart in EF...

Comment: I know its blasphemy but I've never been a fan of Entity Framework. I attended a Microsoft class once where I let that slip and the instructor took the next 5 mins just to tell me how very, very wrong I was.

Answer (score 0):

You should group the data by `pzn` and within each group take the two most recent entries. Also filter the groups that have `> 1` entries:

```
var query = context.BsgApo
                   .Where(a => a.Date <= UserDate)
                   .GroupBy(eL => eL.Pzns)
                   .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                   .SelectMany(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(eL => eL.Date).Take(2))
                   .OrderBy(eL => eL.Pzns).ThenBy(eL => eL.Date)
                   .Select(MapBsgApoToPreisaenderungsErgebnisListe)
                   .ToList();
```

(leaving out some pieces that are not relevant here)

Comment: i added the filtering based on the PZN (your solution runs through the whole table) but received not the number of elements I expect. Have to Investigate it further by using your code. When I get the expected results AND if your code runs faster I'll send you the full Code for edit and mark your answer as correct.